# an absoloutely positioned div will not expand to 100% of its parents height

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to create a div that overlays a canvas element, both of these are contained in a wrapper div. The wrapper has a fixed height but when i add a height of 100% to the overlay div it still has a height of 0. Can anyone help me out with this? Here's the html:

```
<div id="canvas-wrap">
  <canvas id="canvas"   style="background-image: url('<%= @post.image.url%>');"></canvas>
  <div id="overlay">  
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
#canvas-wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  min-height: 400px;

}

#canvas {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border-radius: 7px;
box-shadow: 2px 1px 6px #a0a0a0;
}



#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Is this something to do witht he fact that im using a canvas element as i havent ran into this problem before. Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Your overlay has no **width** so it won't appear anyway - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/WoamQL

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using Background Image property. That will not decide the width of the element. So you can not expect the width change of the element.
So it appears null height instead of zero width. (There was a height but no width)

So assign a fixed width to the parent and align the background image to that width

```
#canvas-wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  min-height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  min-width: 600px;
}

#canvas {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border-radius: 7px;
box-shadow: 2px 1px 6px #a0a0a0;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```